# If a,b are real numbers. Find the least value of $a^2 + ab + b^2 - a - 2b$

Tags: inequality

I tried simple $AM \geq GM$ inequality But no luck

$a^2 + ab + b^2 - a - 2b \geq \sqrt{a^2 * ab * b^2 * (-a) * (-2b)} = \sqrt{2a^4b^4} = a^2b^2\sqrt{2}$

Anwer is $-1$

Comment: Does this have to be solved without differentiation? Otherwise it just amounts to setting the gradient wrt $[a,b]^T$ to 0 and checking that's it's a minimum.

Comment: AM-GM inequality cant be applied to negative numbers

Comment: But if you plot it in wolfram it gives an ellipse with minimum $\approx -0.2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do some square completion:

\begin{eqnarray*}a^2+ab+b^2-a-2b
& = & \left(a+\frac b2\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac b2\right)^2 - a - 2b \\
& = & \left(a+\frac b2\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac b2\right)^2 - \left(a+\frac b2\right) - 3\frac b2 \\
& \stackrel{u=a+\frac b2, v= \frac b2}{=} & \left(u-\frac 12\right)^2 -\frac 14+3\left(v-\frac 12\right)^2-\frac 34 \\
& \geq & -1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

$p=a^2+ab+b^2-a-2b=a^2+a(b-1)+b^2-2b$

We solve polynomial p for $a$:

$a=\frac{-(b-1)\pm \sqrt {\Delta}}2$

$\Delta=(b-1)^2-4b^2+8b$

a can be minimum if $\Delta=0$, in this case

we get $b\approx 1/6$, which gives $a\approx 5/12$ and $p\approx-0.48$ .

Also $b\approx -2$ which gives $a\approx 0.2$ and $p\approx 2.2$. We can see that for b=0, 1 and 2 , p is zero and $\Delta<0$ for $b<0$ and $b>2$.

Value $p=-0.48$ deduces that $0>p_{min}>-1$

Comment: I get $b\approx-1/6$ or $2$